# Cannot read property 'small' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

When trying to access a link as the src of an image from the API, I get an error that says that the property is undefinded.

Here is an example of an item from the API, they all have the same properties:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "date": 1606311631,
    "title": "A Simple Guide to Design Thinking",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "thumbnail": {
      "large": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454692173233-f4f34c12adad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1180&q=80",
      "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454692173233-f4f34c12adad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=590&q=80"
    },
    "author": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "avatar": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492562080023-ab3db95bfbce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80",
      "role": "Product Owner"
    }
  },
```

Now, I mapped all the items from the json, but when I call this function:

```
const AppContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {props.data.map((item) => (
                <ItemWrapper key={item.id} item={item} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

const ItemWrapper = (item) => {
    return (
        <>
            <img src={item.thumbnail.small} alt="" />
            <span className="blueDot"></span>
            <span className="yellowDot"></span>
            <div className="title">{item.title}</div>
            <div className="content">{item.content}</div>
            <div className="authorInfo">
                {item.author.name} - {item.author.role}
            </div>
            <div className="date">{item.date}</div>
        </>
    );
};
```

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined" error. It's reading `item.thumbnail`, but small seems nowhere to be found. How should I correct this?

Comment: "It's reading item.thumbnail, but small seems nowhere to be found." << that's not what the error says. It doesn't say "property `small` is undefined", it says "cannot read property `small` _of_ `undefined`", i.e. it tries to read  `undefined.small` which implies that it's `item.thumbnail` which is `undefined` and not `item.thumbnail.small`. This could be the case if `item` isn't even what you think it is - it's probably something else entirely that doesn't have any `thumbnail` property...

Comment: Check `item` in a debugger (or log it) and see what you are dealing with. You likely don't have there what you think you have.

Comment: @CherryDT oh, I understand. And how should I fix this?

Comment: As said, check what `item` actually is (probably not an item) and then trace back where it came from and what you did wrong - at which point your expectations deviate from the reality - there is likely your bug.

Comment: It looks to me like what Tushar Shahi said - `item` is in reality the `props` object `{ key: ..., item: ... }`.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Now it works. I tried once to do it with props and props.item... but it threw the same error. Maybe I got it wrong the first time.

Comment: Great to hear it works! You could mark Tushar Shahi's answer as "accepted" then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not destructuring your [props](https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0) object properly :

`const ItemWrapper = ({item})`

Comment: I updated the post now about that, but it still does not work